# Paginar resultados php

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una duda, en mi pagina hay un buscador el cual escribo x cosas y me muestra ese resultado relacionado con una paginacion que se extiende hasta la cantidad de cosas que deban aparecer. mi problema es que al querer ir a la pagina 2 de resultados ocurre un error y no se como solucionarlo.
Yo tengo mi index. el cual esta mi buscador:

```
    <form class="d-flex" action="search.php?pagina=1" method="GET">
      <input name="busqueda" id="busqueda" class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success" name="enviar" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

que lleva a mi search.php sin embargo la url es http://localhost/project1/search.php?busqueda=juego&enviar=
y no search.php?pagina=1 como deje aclarado en el form action.

```
<?php
 $busqueda = $_GET['busqueda'];
    $consulta = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM juegos WHERE titulo LIKE '%$busqueda%' ");
    $resultados = $consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $total_articulos_db = $consulta->rowCount();
    $cantidad = 5
    $paginas = ceil($total_articulos_db /$cantidad);
?>
```

El problema aparece cuando quiero acceder a la pagina 2 de los resultados. Aparece este error:
Notice: Undefined index: pagina in C:\xampp\htdocs\project1\search.php on line 24

Además de que los resultados desaparecen y vuelve a imprimir los datos del array.

Comment: `$paginas = ceil($total_articulos_db / 1);` ¿No debería dividirlo entre `$cantidad `? Que entiendo que es lo que quieres mostrar por página?

Comment: Además, el error viene porque solo se hace la búsqueda al hacer el "POST" `if (isset($_POST['enviar']))`, no sé cómo cambias de página, sí hay JS por detrás o algo.. pero `<a>` es un GET.

Comment: Utilizo php. Si uso get tampoco funciona :(

Comment: Estaba escribiendo una respuesta en la pregunta y la eliminaste, ahí te estaba dando algunas indicaciones que conviene pongas en práctica en tu código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aqui te dejo una funcion de paginacion muy util que uso para mis proyectos.
Nota: Esta diseñada con bootstrap para los diseños pero tu la puedes editar a tu manera.

Como comentario cabe mencionar que crear un paginador con metodo POST es muy complejo ya que tendrias que guardar una $_SESSION de la consulta, el ejemplo que yo te dare es utilizando el metodo GET, obtener las variables de busqueda desde tu url
como por ejemplo
`/search.php?titulo=Valor`

**OJO: La funcion esta escrita en mysqli, puedes adaptarla a tu sintaxis si utilizas PDO o cualquier otra forma.**

```
function pagination($query, $per_page = 20,$page = 1, $url = '?'){
    global $conn;
    if($query){
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as `num` FROM $query";
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($mysqli,$query));
        $total = $row['num'];
        $adjacents = "2"; 
 
        $page = ($page == 0 ? 1 : $page);  
        $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;                               
         
        $prev = $page - 1;                          
        $next = $page + 1;
        $lastpage = ceil($total/$per_page);
        $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;
         
        $pagination = "";
        if($lastpage > 1)
        {   
            $pagination .= "<ul class='pagination pagination-sm'>";
            if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))
            {   
                for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<li class='active'><a>$counter</a></li>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";                    
                }
            }
            elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))
            {
                if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))     
                {
                    for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination.= "<li class='active'><a>$counter</a></li>";
                        else
                            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";                    
                    }
                    $pagination.= "<li class='disabled'><span>...</span></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lpm1'>$lpm1</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a></li>";      
                }
                elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
                {
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=1'>1</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=2'>2</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li class='disabled'><span>...</span></li>";
                    for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination.= "<li class='active'><a>$counter</a></li>";
                        else
                            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";                    
                    }
                    $pagination.= "<li class='disabled'><span>...</span></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lpm1'>$lpm1</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a></li>";      
                }
                else
                {
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=1'>1</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=2'>2</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li class='disabled'><span>...</span></li>";
                    for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination.= "<li class='active'><a>$counter</a></li>";
                        else
                            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";                    
                    }
                }
            }
             
            if ($page < $counter - 1){ 
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$next'>»</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lastpage'>Last</a></li>";
            }else{
                $pagination.= "<li class='disabled'><a>»</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li class='disabled'><a>Last</a></li>";
            }
            $pagination.= "</ul>\n";      
        }
    }
    return $pagination;
}
```

Al momento de mostrar el paginador tienes que definir unas variables

```
<?php
$page = (int) (!isset($_GET["page"]) ? 1 : $_GET["page"]); //detecta en que pagina esta
$limit = 20; // limite de consultas a mostrar por cada pagina
$startpoint = ($page * $limit) - $limit; // calcula desde donde empieza la consulta en la base de datos.

$busqueda = stripslashes($_GET['titulo']);
$consulta = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM juegos WHERE titulo LIKE '%$busqueda%' LIMIT $startpoint, $limit");
$paginator = pagination("juegos WHERE titulo LIKE '%$busqueda%'",$limit,$page,'?titulo='.$busqueda.'&');

echo $paginator;
```

Comment: Y como podria hacerlo con $_SESSION? mi problema es que si uso get funciona todo correcto excepto al querer pasar a la pagina 2. que me aparece lo siguiente:

`Notice: Undefined variable: consulta in C:\xampp\htdocs\project1\search.php on line 20

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\project1\search.php:20 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\project1\search.php on line 20
`

Comment: Vengo estancando con esto ya hace tiempo sin poder buscarle la vuelta al asunto

Comment: Creo que el problema viene a que realmente no estás enviando el parámetro. El action debería ser "search.php" y añadir un parámetro hide <input type="hidden" name="página" value="1"/> par que así el formulario te envié ese parámetro (como haces con el búsqueda)

Comment: @NahuelNavarrete Nos podrias compartir tu codigo completo para tener mas informacion sobre que linea de codigo es la que tiene el error, porquie parece que ese error corresponde a que no se esta haciendo la consulta exitosamente.

Comment: @NahuelNavarrete El detalle es que en tu consulta no estas utilizando lo que es `LIMIT` ya que eso permite paginar los resultados de la base de datos, lo que tienes en tu codigo es que solamente cuentas los valores y ya pero al momento de mostrarlos solamente te van a aparecer los  primeros. comparte tu codigo completo para ver porque no funciona el que te escribi.

Comment: @Ruben hola, gracias por la ayuda de antemano! modifique la pregunta con los codigos del form del buscador y el lugar donde me tira el problema. Se precisa de otra fuente mas? gracias por la ayuda reitero!

Comment: @NahuelNavarrete Tambien hay un detalle, el formulario se ejecuta en una pagina que no tiene valores predeterminados con tus condiciones. `action="search.php?pagina=1"` no requiere el atributo `page=1`

Comment: @NahuelNavarrete te comparto este gist como ejemplo [Search.php](https://gist.github.com/RubeVi17/906e666dff6cb8dde0f693860be46b54) te puedes basar en la query de este script para darte una idea, ya que tienes que considerar el manejo de las bases de datos, a menos que utilices una API REST donde obtengas los datos y los decodifiques.

Comment: @Ruben YA PUDE SOLUCIONARLO... ESTOY MUY FELIZ GRACIAS POR SU DEDICACION AL QUERER AYUDARME. gracias a todos!! ahora tengo que investigar sobre como hacer funcionar el paginador. Estuve trabajando estos dias y no pude avanzar en el proyecto pero ya esta. que alegria!

Comment: Que tal @NahuelNavarrete de nada ya sabes que estamos para ayudarnos, te funciona al momento de mostrar los resultados pero el paginador no? o como?

Comment: @Ruben resolvi el buscador , me dio problemas el paginador pero lo estuve estudiando a fondo consultando informacion en google y pude tambien solucionarlo. Muchas gracias!